# how to make some form elements required on clicking some other form elements.

Tags: jquery, html

I am newbie in jquery and JS, I want to do something like this. I have a a sets of radio buttons, On clicking one radio say products, user need to select product type too. How can I do that with Jquery? My code is:

```
   <div class="form-group"> 
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Menu Type </label>
    <div class="col-sm-2" >Product<input type="radio" class="form-control" name="menu_type" id="title" value="1" required ></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">CMS Page<input type="radio" class="form-control" name="menu_type" id="title" value="2" required ></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">Testimonials<input type="radio" class="form-control" name="menu_type" id="title" value="3" required ></div>
    </div>
    <?=form_error('menu_type');?>

    <div id="p_type_div" style="display: none;" class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Product Type</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9" >
    <select name="product_type" id="sub_category" data-placeholder="Choose One" class="width100 select2-offscreen" tabindex="-1" title="" required> 
    <option value="" >----------</option> 
    <?php foreach($p_category as $rows_cat):?>           
    <option value="<?php echo $rows_cat->id ?>"><?php echo $rows_cat->cat_name; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
```

script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#Menu_form input').on('change', function() {
       var menu_type=$('input[name=menu_type]:checked', '#Menu_form').val(); 
       if(menu_type=='1'){
         $('#p_type_div').show();
       }
       else{
        $('#p_type_div').hide();
       }
    });
    </script>
```

I want to make the product_type field required when user checks the product radio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```
if(menu_type=='1'){
    $("#sub_category").prop('required',true);
    $('#p_type_div').show();
}else{
    $("#sub_category").prop('required',false);
    $('#p_type_div').hide();
}
```

Comment: I have one more question to ask to you. Can You answer it?

Comment: Sure. I'll Try.

Comment: I have to a parent attribute and a its child okay. Now When users selects their parents, then it should be automatically filled.

Comment: filled? Sorry, I am not able to understand the question here. What should be filled with what?

Comment: suppose this is parent
<input type="radio" id="sab" name="type1" value="1" >
and this is its child
<input type="text" name="type_value" value=" " >
Now when that radio is clicked input field type_value should have value type1 filled . There are more than two input radios. This is the case .

Comment: Assuming you have an id/class in input tag in which value has to be filled. On the radio 'change' event check which radio button is clicked and according to that. use $("#type_value").val("type1");
There is a way of doing this same thing without conditions but it is a little complicated to explain here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160186/discussion-between-suz-aann-shrestha-and-paras).